# UI Implementation for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, android-recyclerview, layout

How to implement this UI in both android and ios,

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think Material Chip Layout is what you are looking for.
Attaching links for you reference.

[Implement Material Chip Layout in IOS](https://material.io/components/chips/ios)

[Implement Material Chip Layout in Android](https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/chips-material-components-for-android-46001664a40f)

Comment: thanks but, I need a custom view or layout kind of thing.

Comment: Also, my label response comes as a list from the backend.

Comment: Use FlexBox layout manager with recyclerview for android in that case. Check for similar alternative in IOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for flex layout: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html